# Can I find a bookshelf that has book A and book (B, C, or D) in one activerecord query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Imagine these associations:

```
class Bookshelf
  has_many :book_associations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :books, through: :book_associations
end

class Book
  has_many :book_associations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bookshelves, through: :book_associations
end

class BookAssociation
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :bookshelf
end
```

I need to find all bookshelves that contain a book with ID A and a book with ID B, C, or D

I can do this in a multi-step process using ruby like:

```
bookshelf_ids1 = Book.find(A).bookshelves.pluck(:id)
bookshelf_ids2 = Book.where(id: [B, C, D]).map(&:bookshelves).flatten.uniq.pluck(:id)
Bookshelf.where(id: bookshelf_ids1 & bookshelf_ids2)
```

But there must be a way to do this in one line, either through ActiveRecord or a raw SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this question boils down to is that you're looking for an intersection of `Bookshelf` objects in set `A` (contains book with ID `a`) and `Bookshelf` objects in set `B` (contains book with ID in array `b`).

I don't recall seeing any easy way to express this intersection using a single `ActiveRecord` query. And as you probably have suspected, a multi query approach wouldn't scale well. Why run three queries when you can run one?

So here's my solution:

### Finding the Bookshelve IDs

```
SELECT DISTINCT b1.bookshelf_id
FROM book_associations b1
    INNER JOIN book_associations b2 ON b1.bookshelf_id = b2.bookshelf_id
WHERE b1.book_id = 1 AND b2.book_id IN (2,3,4);
```

This is a bit complicated so let me break it down. We are joining the `book_associations` table on itself, on its own `bookshelf_id`. This has the effect of making two tables available for filtering. We then filter query table `b1` for the first criteria (`ID = 1`), and filter query table `b2` for the other criteria (`ID in (2,3,4)`). With the `INNER JOIN` we are then ensuring that we are only getting the intersection of tables `b1` and `b2`. We retrieve only the `bookshelf_id` because we're looking only to retrieve the bookshelves. Finally, the `DISTINCT` query is the SQL equivalent of `.uniq` and ensures the returned values are unique.

### Retrieving the Bookshelves

From here, we then need to instantiate the `Bookshelf` objects. While we could do this:

```
bookshelf_ids = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.query(["SELECT DISTINCT b1.bookshelf_id
FROM book_associations b1
    INNER JOIN book_associations b2 ON b1.bookshelf_id = b2.bookshelf_id
WHERE b1.book_id = ? AND b2.book_id IN (?);", 1, [2,3,4]])
bookshelves = Bookshelf.find(bookshelf_ids)
```

It's still two steps. Here's a single-step solution:

```
Bookshelf.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM bookshelves bs
WHERE bs.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT b1.bookshelf_id
FROM book_associations b1
    INNER JOIN book_associations b2 ON b1.bookshelf_id = b2.bookshelf_id
WHERE b1.book_id = ? AND b2.book_id IN (?)
)", first_id,second_ids])
```

The `Bookshelf.select_by_sql` command instantiates records from the query results. The `bookshelf_ids` are retrieved in the subquery and used as a condition for the query on the `bookshelves` table.

### Caveats

<strike>I haven't tested this code and can't confirm it will work, but the broad strokes should be correct.</strike>

The SQL should be valid for PostgresQL, but may require some tweaks depending on your specific DB implementation.

### Edit

I've corrected the code above, I had joined the `book_associations` table on the wrong column (`id`) instead of the correct column `bookshelf_id`, and the subquery was returning the wrong column (again `id` when it should've been `bookshelf_id`).

I've created a [proof of concept](https://github.com/richseviora/cross-join-example) with test included.

Comment: Thanks @richard-seviora, I posted a cleaned up and simplified version of this in my original post, but it still doesn't work for me.  The simplification was to make it just return a bookshelf with book A and book B in it, since that seems to be where the difficulty comes in.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Could you check your entered code vs mine? I'm seeing changes in your answer that will break the solution.

Comment: But I'm not sure if those are intentional changes or not?

Comment: those were intentional changes, I didn't know what ```INNER JOIN hook_associations``` was meant to be in your code, and assumed it was meant to join to bookshelves.

Comment: Ah, typo on my end. Should have been book associations.

Comment: But how (and why) would you join 2 book_associations with the same ID?  I'll try that, maybe that's some SQL voodoo that I don't know about but it seems strange.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work.  Still confused at the concept of it.

Comment: Corrected my code. The self-join was on the wrong column `id` instead of the `bookshelf_id` column.